# Javascript: Which of these implementations is more efficient/better?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an icon that when clicked will increase the value of a number input.

I initially wrote it as:

```
 $('.icon-chevron-up').click(function(){
      var input = $(this).next();
  var value = eval(input.val());
  input.val((value+1).toString());
  $(this).next.val(value+1);
 });
```

I then rewrote it as:

```
 $('.icon-chevron-up').click(function(){
  $(this).next().val((eval($(this).next().val()) + 1).toString());
 });
```

Is there a preferred way of doing this? And if so, why?

Comment: Instead of using eval to parse integers, use `parseInt`.

Comment: `eval()` comes with security concerns ;)

Comment: Try:  `$(this).next().val( ++$(this).next().val() + '' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those would be the best for efficiency. `eval` is not needed and if you want performance you should cache your selectors. There are a couple ways you could make it more efficient but I would do it like this:

```
$('.icon-chevron-up').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this), 
      val = $this.next().val();
  $this.next().val( ++val + '' );
});
```

`++` casts `val` to a number and adds `1`. `+ ''` casts the previous number to a string.

If you want something less terse (more readable I guess):

```
$this.next().val( (parseInt( val,10 ) + 1).toString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by input? should it be text input or just a html tag?

```
<button class="icon-chevron-up">Increase</button>
<div id="numinput">12</div>

var input = $('#numinput').html();
$('.icon-chevron-up').click(function(){    
    input++;
    $('#numinput').html(input);     
});
```